# Error exception causing print to fail - python2

Tags: python, exception, printing, passwords, cracking

Here is a snippet from my code. For some reason it simply won't print out the second line saying "Cracking took 10 seconds" or whatever, but this first bit saying Password Found: does work... Why?

```
def connect(host, user, password, release):
    global Found
    global Fails
    global startTime

    try:
        s = pxssh.pxssh()
        s.login(host, user, password)
        print '[+] Password Found: ' + password
        print 'Cracking the password took' + datetime.now()-startTime + 'seconds.'
    Found = True

    except Exception, e:
        if 'read_nonblocking' in str(e):
        Fails += 1
            time.sleep(5)
            connect(host, user, password, False)
    elif 'synchronize with original prompt' in str(e):
        time.sleep(1)
        connect(host, user, password, False)
```

Comment: care to share the exception?

Comment: None, that is my issue. I am guessing the exception is causing it to go wrong. I am unsure though.

Comment: It may be because `datetime.now()-startTime` isn't a string, try with `str(datetime.now()-startTime)`. Also `Found = True` doesn't have a correct identation

Comment: The Found = True does have correct indentation, stackoverflow just messed it up. Just to point out I am running this within the commandline as it requires extra arguements (-t for example)

Comment: If adding `str(...)` doesn't fix the issue, remove try-except and update your question with the traceback, that will help to find a solution

Comment: `str()` did not work, and I received this error

`cannot concatenate 'str' and 'datetime.datetime' objects`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to concatenate two different things (`datetime` and `str`), try converting the `datetime` to str as:

```
def connect(host, user, password, release):
    global Found
    global Fails
    global startTime

    try:
        s = pxssh.pxssh()
        s.login(host, user, password)
        print '[+] Password Found: ' + password
        print 'Cracking the password took' + str(datetime.now()-startTime) + 'seconds.'
        Found = True

    except Exception, e:
        if 'read_nonblocking' in str(e):
            Fails += 1
            time.sleep(5)
            connect(host, user, password, False)
        elif 'synchronize with original prompt' in str(e):
            time.sleep(1)
            connect(host, user, password, False)
```

Moreover, you shouldn't trap all kind `Exception`, just those you need.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably that you haven't set `startTime`, but you masked it by over-broad exception handling. Either remove the `try/except`, select some other exception to trap, or simply include a bare `raise` command in your exception handler and you should see a NameError because of the absence of initialization. Fix that and your code has more of a chance.

Comment: I am getting this error
`cannot concatenate 'str' and 'datetime.datetime' objects`

Comment: In which your true error is revealed, as pointed out by Ruben above. Exception handling has to be carefully managed to ensure you don't trap and ignore spurious errors.